# App doesnt show in Google play for tablet

Tags: android, tablet, google-play

My app's build sdk is **Google APIs 2.2 [API 8]** and has all the layout necessary for small and large phones and tablet also. The problem is that it is not shown in google play for tablet.
manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.myapp"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="2.0"
android:installLocation="auto" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"

     />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"  android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"  />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.test.myapp.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ..............
        ...........
```

Read other stackoverflow threads but can't solve my problem.
What is the problem here ?
Thanx !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to add this:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer guys, i changed the targetsdkversion to 10 and added android:xlargeScreens="true", it works

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is on
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"

try to set it to higher Version , 10 or above...