# Google Play doesn't show my application for Tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I deployed my application on Google Play and it doesn't show as available for Tablet.
It has support for xlarge screens (as suggested [in the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438935/app-doesnt-show-in-google-play-for-tablet))

The reason it doesn't show is that it requires 3G, Telephony and some other things that a Tablet doesn't (normally) have, but are absolutely neccesary for my Smartphone version, and are very nice to have on tablet as well.

**So, my question essentially is: is there a way to set these requirements as "needed but not must" or require them at runtime and handle their absence in my Application?**

Thanks

Comment: if you add `required="false"` to these permissions i guess it will show your app for tablets too. at least in my situation it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to handle that.

For setting this you need to make all these requirements as **feature** not **permission**.Then make it as not a must needed feature by adding `android:required="false"`

Like this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

See the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this document. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

You can add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>` to your manifest.